# Listening css and javascript events

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

I'm working on a project of copying one user actions from one browser to another browser.

Both users are looking at the same page.
I created the enviroment where I can transfer one user mouse movements to another browser (users can see their own mouse and mouse of another user).
Other user can see movements and clicks and when somebody click on link both browsers go to that url.

Now, I have css/javascript menu on the page, and I would like to transfer hover actions (when first user hover the menu link the other user will see the same hover action on his page).

Any idea on what to listen and pass to other browser so i can trigger the same event there?
I'm working in jQuery.

UPDATE

Hovering is only an example of what I need. 
I want to catch every css/javascript action on the page and I don't know what will it be (Hovering, entering text, changing radio button state)

I need to listen to every element and to know what happend, so I can transfer it and do the same action on other side.

Comment: The same way as you're already listening to mouse moves and clicks. Another event to listen to add in jQuery in this case would be **hover** where you provide two handlers: one for getting over an element and another when getting out of it.

Comment: Are you doing some kind of **XSS attack** to observe other people's browsing? Wonder what happens when user click a link to an external site? If this would be a browser plugin then it would continue to work afterwards...

Comment: I guess the main question in your case isn't *which event to listen to* but rather how do I **show a hover in a transferred session because mouse cursor in that one is not on the element**. Is that the actual question?

Comment: hm, incredible,  you already send to another browser half of your soul, but stuck on hover events...

Comment: And tell us what does CSS have to do with this and what CSS events are you implying to in your question title? (and please start answering these questions).

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, I assume that he wants to trigger the css `a:hover` styles when the interaction on the remote browser shows the pointer being over a link.

Comment: First thing I want to implement is css hover action. I thought it would be a good thing to start.

Comment: After reading your answer I realized that i need js that would listen to any javascript action thah happend and transfer it, and css hover to make separately

Comment: @Davis Thomas, yes. I mentioned menu navigation becaouse it has combined css and javascript. Css for hover and JS for drop downs.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, yes how to show an action on remote web page is the problem. But also what is the action that happened

Comment: @mgalesic: Maybe you should read [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) and learn a bit about the `event` object which holds all the information you may be interested in during some event handling.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik, I see event.type can return the current event. But I'm still in the dark how could I catch "any" event without hard coding all of them and create an event for every one?

Comment: @mgalesic: You won't be able to bind to *all* events directly. Your best bet would be `.on("click mousemove keyup keydown...", ...)` and have one handler for all events that you specify. This is as close as it gets to handling them all. *All* can also be rather vague, because not all elements support same set of events.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you wanted to capture hover events on links:

```
<a href="http://example.com">A link!</a>
```

In your JavaScript, [after the DOM is ready](https://gist.github.com/3486751), you could put something like this:

```
$('a').on('hover', function() {
    // do something!
});
```

---

What about on a particular link?

```
<a href="http://example.com" id="this-one-link">A great link too.</a>
```

Your JavaScript will look something like this:

```
$('#this-one-link').on('hover', function() {
    // do something!
});
```

---

You could also make a *class* of links. In this example, the first two links will trigger the event, but not the last one.

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="hover-event">Example 1</a>
<a href="http://example.com" class="hover-event">Example 2</a>
<a href="http://example.com">Example 3</a>
<a href="http://example.com">Example 4</a>
```

And your JavaScript:

```
$('#this-one-link').on('hover', function() {
    // do something!
});
```

Comment: Could you just bind to a bunch of events? "hover", "change", etc?

Comment: I think I run onto a problem.
I would need to know what is an ID od A element that class is applied, but now every A has ID.

Olso have would i know what class is applied?

Comment: @ Evan Hahn: this is what i really need:
What is the event that just happened